# How to add an external library inside microsoft's power bi developer tools and export in pbiviz

Tags: typescript, powerbi

I am trying to create a custom visualization inside powerbi using [pykcharts.js](http://pykcharts.com). however i am unable to import my file pykcharts.js into the dev tool's console. I have tried passing cdn path like this

```
/// <reference path="https://cdn.rawgit.com/akshayda04/powerbi-cdn/master/pykcharts/pykcharts.1.1.0.min.ts"/>
```

as it is using typescript, but it is not accepting it.
Is there any way to include my file and suggest me the ways to export file in pbiviz?

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve it using the [jQuery.getScript()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) method.

I just tested it and it's works fine withe the Power BI Developer Tools and custom visualisation. I tried it with the [jQuery.browser](https://github.com/gabceb/jquery-browser-plugin) plugin like this:

```
        $.getScript("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-browser/0.1.0/jquery.browser.js", function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
           //Now the external scripts is loaded. From now on you could use it
        });
```

And, after it's correctly loaded (so when the `jQuery.getScript` success callback is invoked) you could easily use it, in my example it's just `$.browser`. But you need to remember that it will be available only after it's loaded. So you need to adjust your code to wait for it before processing data and creating visualization. Also good practice is to check if your script isn't loaded already (it isn't necessary to download it twice).

Another, but very inelegant solution, is to copy and paste scripts that you want to include to the Dev Tools (for example at the end of the file).

I don't know if there is any other options that is recommended by the Power BI team. For now I can't find any information about it, maybe in the future they will add functionality to import scripts via reference.

I hope that this will help you. Good luck!

Comment: I have been struggling with this for days.  I would ideally like to use kendo which has a typescript library but I would gladly settle for bootstrap or any high level widget lirbary.  Does anyone have examples of working integration in a custom visual that uses the online dev tool?

Answer (score 1):

The new tools allow you to do this easily. https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-visuals-tools

Here is the link on specifically adding external libraries. https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-visuals/blob/master/Tutorial/ExternalLibraries.md